# XCode and Git: Opening branch in XCode always makes changes to the project file

Tags: xcode, git, gitkraken

I just started at a company that uses Git, I was previously at a company that used SVN.

We've got many branches off of our master and every time I check one out and open it, XCode makes changes to the project file or to a storyboard, even if all I did was opened it to review. For example, on Branch A here, I wanted to just ensure something was present in the UI so I checked it out and ran it. I then went to check out another branch and I got an error that I had changes to check in before I could (I am using GitKraken).

Here's an example of the changes that get generated:

[image]

If I check these in they present a whole lot of conflicts when I go to merge back into master. Is there something I can do in XC or Git to get around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Xcode only does changes by itself to the project files if its version is updated. In the screenshot it looks like you moved the textfield about 2 points. Maybe this happened accidentally? Merging project or storyboard files is everybody's nightmare...

Comment: I disagree, we have multiple storyboards and I will see the M symbol next to some that I haven't even opened. It's easy enough to just delete the changes. But do agree, the merges are awful...be it Git or SVN...